# How to properly disable Linux deep C-States from a C program?

Tags: c, linux

On Linux OS CPUs run on different power-saving states called the C-states. They are ranging from C0 to Cn. C0 is the state with maximum performance, but consume more power. So to maximize performance one can disable transition to deeper states. This can be done by writing 0 to the **/dev/cpu_dma_latency** file.
See: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-dev-cpu_dma_latency-device-file-on-Linux-systems

The problem is that there is two way of writing to the file.

1. **Write the number 0**.

   ```
    FILE *fp;  

    void start_low_latency()
    {  
        char target = '0';  

        fp= fopen("/dev/cpu_dma_latency", "r+");  
        if (fp == NULL)
        {  
           fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open PM QOS file: %s", strerror(errno));  
           exit(errno);  
        }  

        fputc(target, fp);  
      }  

    void stop_low_latency()
    { 
        if (fp != NULL)//if (fp == NULL)
          fclose(fp);
    }
   ```

Reference:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/8/html/optimizing_rhel_8_for_real_time_for_low_latency_operation/assembly_controlling-power-management-transitions_optimizing-rhel8-for-real-time-for-low-latency-operation

2. **Binary write of the number 0**.

   ```
    static int laptop = 0;
    static int latency_target_fd = -1;
    static int32_t latency_target_value = 0;  

    static void start_low_latency()//static void set_latency_target()
    {
        struct stat s;
        int err;  

        if (laptop) {
            warn("not setting cpu_dma_latency to save battery power\n");
            return;
        }  

        errno = 0;
        err = stat("/dev/cpu_dma_latency", &s);  

        if (err == -1) {
            err_msg_n(errno, "WARN: stat /dev/cpu_dma_latency failed");
            return;
        }

        errno = 0;
        latency_target_fd = open("/dev/cpu_dma_latency", O_RDWR);  

        if (latency_target_fd == -1) {
            err_msg_n(errno, "WARN: open /dev/cpu_dma_latency");
            return;
        }  

        errno = 0;
        err = write(latency_target_fd, &latency_target_value, 4);  

        if (err < 1) {
            err_msg_n(errno, "# error setting cpu_dma_latency to %d!", latency_target_value);
            close(latency_target_fd);
            return;
        }
        printf("# /dev/cpu_dma_latency set to %dus\n", latency_target_value);
    }

    static void stop_low_latency()
    {
        if (latency_target_fd >= 0)
            close(latency_target_fd);
    }
   ```

Reference: https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests/+/stable/devel/v1.0.1/src/cyclictest/cyclictest.c

**Which method is the right one?**

Comment: `the right one?` How to detect what is "right"?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question. I think one of the two methods does it wrong

Comment: Why do you think that? What does it mean to "do it wrong"?

Comment: One method write a number as text while the second does a binary write of the number. They are clearly different.
So i think one of the two methods is wrong and will not work.

Comment: The two are clearly *different*, but that does not require that either one be *wrong*.  It may be that the kernel recognizes both alternatives.  Inasmuch as both approaches seem to be documented, I think you should at least consider that they might both work as desired.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  "It may be that the kernel recognizes both alternatives." I am not Linux expert but I personally find it surprising. Is there a way to be sure about it?

Comment: Did you (after reboot) try `od` on the file? If it's like some `/proc` or `/sys` files you can get the current value. And the usual is a _text_ string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/power/pm_qos_interface.html),

> To register the default PM QoS target for the CPU latency QoS, the
> process must open /dev/cpu_dma_latency.
>
> As long as the device node is held open that process has a registered
> request on the parameter.
>
> To change the requested target value, the process needs to write an
> s32 value to the open device node. Alternatively, it can write a hex
> string for the value using the 10 char long format e.g. "0x12345678".
> This translates to a cpu_latency_qos_update_request() call.
>
> To remove the user mode request for a target value simply close the
> device node.

Note well that there are two alternatives for how to express the requested C-state value:

- write a 32-bit integer, OR
- write a hex string

For the latter case, the docs do specify a 10-`char` format, but it is entirely plausible that the implementation also accepts shorter hex strings.  In that case, these alternatives each cover one of your cases, meaning *both* are acceptable.